# How to load js files on crudbooster

Tags: laravel, crudbooster

I am trying to load a js file but this code based on the documentation is not working.

```
$this->load_js = array();
$this->load_js[] = asset("js/nyel/test.js");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only works on the public folder. I was putting it on resources folder at first.